# Why do thermal_zone1 in /sys/class has so many subsystem inside thermal_zone1?

Tags: filesystems

I was trying to look into the device temperature. What I found has puzzled me. When I go to `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/subsystem` it has endless loop.

It would be clear from the output of `pwd` as follows:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1
```

Output of `ls` in pwd:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1/subsystem/thermal_zone1$ 
ls
available_policies  k_d  k_po  mode    passive  power  subsystem          temp  uevent
integral_cutoff
```

And it does not end here, I can keep doing `cd` into `subsystem` folder and so on and so forth.

So, my question is why it has so many `subsystem` inside `thermal_zone1`? Is it normal?

Device info:

```
$uname -a
Linux chips 4.4.154-1124-rockchip-ayufan-*** #1 SMP Mon Oct 22 20:59:41 UTC 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167207/why-does-linux-store-cpu-temperatures-on-so-many-files) answer but I do not think it addresses my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.

The `subsystem` links under `/sys/class` aren’t subsystems of their containing directory, but rather links to the subsystem containing them. So `/sys/class/thermal/*/subsystem` links back to `/sys/class/thermal`, and you get the loop you’ve run into.

Put another way, `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/subsystem` isn’t a subsystem of `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1`; it points to `/sys/class/thermal`, the subsystem of which `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1` is a part.

This setup makes a little more sense when considered that `/sys/class/thermal/*` are themselves symlinks which point to entries under `/sys/devices`, *i.e.* outside the `/sys/class` tree...

Comment: Thank you. I see `9032 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 18  2013 subsystem -> ../../../../class/thermal`